# SQLite syntax error when using 'LIKE'

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using the following syntax on an SQLite database:

```
DELETE * FROM places WHERE city LIKE "Barcelona"
```

But I receive an error similar to the following:

> "Error syntax near *".

What is wrong?

Comment: just remove  the `*`

Answer (score 1):

Use Like query as

```
  DELETE FROM <TABLENAME> where field1 like '%test%' OR field2 like '%test%' OR ... fieldLast like %test%'
```

so your query will be :

```
DELETE from places WHERE city like '%Barcelona%'
```

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out after just some research, a related question:

The correct query is:

```
DELETE from places WHERE city LIKE "%Barcelona%"
```